# Nikon D3300 - no exposure indicator displayed while in Aperture Priority

Tags: aperture-priority, nikon-d3300

I have had my new Nikon for around 2 months and am learning about settings and modes. I have lost the exposure indicator in the information display. What did I do to cause this?
Thanks